# Python 3.6 install RAKE

Tags: python, rake

I'm so sorry if this is a stupid question... I want to use RAKE to extract keywords from a file. But I couldn't install RAKE. I tried the Github tutorial https://github.com/fabianvf/python-rake
I use Anaconda Python 3.6 and it says Pip is included by default after Py3.4. I followed the tutorial but I couldn't install it :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HblU2.png)

Comment: You need to run that from the command shell, not from within Python.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `pip install python-rake` from command shell/ Terminal.

Comment: Python-rake successfully installed and it IS a stupid question but thank you so so much!